# JS Canvas - how to fill area with bitmap?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Using JavaScript's Canvas - how to fill specific area with a bitmap? And not just draw the bitmap, but for example fill a 100x100 rectangle with 20x20 px bitmap?

```
graphics.beginBitmapFill(bmd, matr);
graphics.draw()
```

This is ActionScript3 code, that I know how to use. I'm searching for JavaScript alternative to it.

Comment: Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Describe your problem. What do you want? What is going wrong?

Comment: i know the ctx.settransform. but the transform is the fillRect,not the bmd self matr.not same the flash,graphics.beginbitmapfill

Comment: Where are you talking about?

Comment: You really need to provide more context to your question. As it is, it's not clear, what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As per link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp, you can proceed as follows:

- assuming you have a 100px by 100px canvas in your html:

  ```
  <canvas id="cv"></canvas>
  ```
- you can process it in JavaScript as follows:

  ```
  var canvas, context;

  canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ```
- you can place your 20x20 image with the upper left corner at 10px to the left and 30px to the top as follows

  ```
  context.drawImage('img.jpg', 10, 30, 20, 20);
  ```

My first open-source JavaScript library is entirely based on HTML5 canvas, where you can see more examples on how to work with it in JS:
http://pickled-plugins.github.io/ripsaw-demo/#pages/home

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. I'll get back to it when I figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(image, "repeat");
context.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
```

full code at
http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-fill-pattern-html5-canvas/